# How to create a new Charge/Credit in Supplier Account via ABSL or Webservice?

Tags: sap-business-bydesign

I´m trying to create a new Charge/Credit into my system SAP Business ByDesign, but I did not find an object inside the repository explorer in the SDK nor a Webservice, can you tell me if it's possible to access this view via code or using an OData service or any kind of Webservice?

I have tried accessing via Payables, Supplier Account, Receivables, Customer Account, but I did not find anything that allows me to modify or create a new charge/credit.

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there are only few SAP Business ByDesign APIs in the API Hub. However; SAP Business ByDesign offers the possibility to generate custom OData APIs out of the business documents such as sales order, purchase order, supplier invoice, customer invoice, product master data and business partner master data. The custom OData APIs can then be used to build extension applications – among others - in SAP cloud platform using SAP Cloud SDK. Here are some reference materials that can help you in the creation and consumption of SAP Business ByDesign Custom OData APIs:

- You can find examples and descriptions in the following GitHub
  repository:
  https://github.com/SAP-samples/sapbydesign-api-samples
- The following video clip will guide you on how to generate custom
  OData APIs on SAP Business ByDesign:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6mF_1hFths
- You can refer to my blog post series on how to consume SAP Business
  ByDesign custom OData APIs in SAP Cloud Platform using SAP Cloud SDK.
  https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/03/sap-business-bydesign-side-by-side-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

A quick search found the following blog post about *SAP Business ByDesign*: [OData API Examples](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/27/sap-business-bydesign-api-usage-samples/).

If there is an exposed OData Service, then you can create an OData VDM with the *SAP Cloud SDK*.

Alternatively you can take a look into the dedicated [entry in the SAP API Business Hub](https://api.sap.com/package/BYD?section=Artifacts). There are some SOAP services listed. If one fits your needs, then you can consider using the SAP Cloud SDK to invoke SOAP requests (or use any other client to do so).

You can also reach out to the colleagues who maintain the project. Maybe they offer a well maintained OData specification somewhere.